# Python IDLE from MacPorts can't start

Tags: macports, python

I tried installing the python27 and python32 packages via MacPorts in Mac OS X 10.6.8. It includes the standard IDLE, Python Launcher, and Build Applet applications. However, when I start them, their icons would bounce briefly in the dock then disappear.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this problem so the IDLE (and other applications) installed via MacPorts can start and function correctly?

Thank you!

BTW, having only one Python version installed by MacPorts didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDLE requires TK to work. You need the tkinter package for your version of python in order for IDLE to work. You probably want py27-tkinter and py32-tkinter. Unfortunately, you'll probably have to go with the default xll version, the +quartz variant is not well maintained upstream. It won't build in x64 on Lion+ or with Xcode 4.4+ because it uses deprecated QuickDraw APIs which don't exist in the 10.7+ SDKs. Xcode no longer includes a 10.6 SDK, but you might be able to get it to work on 10.6.

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32329